# How to get the 'parent' of a focused cell in UIcollectionview cell with swift - tvOS

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I made some sort of Netflix layout for my tvOS application, which contains several collection views named: `featuredCollectionView` and `standardCollectionView`.

I have a variable which contains the current focused cell. The only thing I want is to get the current collection view of selected cell. Can anyone help me with it?

**The code**

```
func pressedThePlayPauseButton() {

   if let focusedCell = UIScreen.main.focusedView as? UICollectionViewCell{

       let collectionViewOfFocusedCell = ...
```

Comment: I hope this link  https://github.com/VikasPrajapati27/CollectionViewFocus will help you.

Answer (score 6):

You can always walk up the view hierarchy:

```
    var parentCollectionView = self.superview
    while parentCollectionView is UICollectionView != true {
        parentCollectionView = parentCollectionView?.superview
    }
```

You can change UICollectionView above to the subclass you are looking for if you need to go through multiple collection views.  The easier way is to just give your cell a weak reference to your collectionView in cellForItemAtIndexPath; this also works for your view controller instead of your collectionView which is likely what you really want the reference to.  It has to be weak since the collectionView retains the cell; otherwise you create a cycle.

```
    class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
        weak var customCollectionViewController: CustomCollectionViewController?

    }

    class CustomCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: CustomCollectionViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
            cell.customCollectionViewController = self
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand what you're doing here, but I'm not using a UICollectionViewConroller but just several UICollectionViews. How would that work in my case?

Comment: Yes as long as the type is correct and you set the weak reference to the correct collectionView; the weak reference works for any reference type.